# How do you rename auto-generated associative tables in Entity Framework code first?

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I know how to name tables and specify schemas in the OnModelCreating() method based on the classes that map to them.  I.e.,

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().ToTable("Customers", schemaName: "Ordering");
```

But what about many-to-many relationships that result in an auto-generated associative table?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, found the answer here:

[Mapping association tables in EF 4.1 code first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965972/mapping-association-tables-in-ef-4-1-code-first)

For some reason, I didn't encounter this on my original search for existing posts.